# A function to return a sign

Tags: c#, .net, math

I know this will really turn out to be simple, but my brain is just not working. I need a function in C# that will return -1 if the integer passed to the function has a negative sign, return 1 if the integer has a positive sign and return 0 if the number passed is 0. So for example:

```
int Sign=SignFunction(-82); // Should return -1
int Sign2=SignFunction(197); // Should return 1
int Sign3=SignFunction(0);   // Should return 0
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is already in the framework.  Just use [Math.Sign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sign(VS.80).aspx)...

```
int sign = Math.Sign(-82); // Should return -1
int sign2 = Math.Sign(197); // Should return 1
int sign3 = Math.Sign(0);   // Should return 0
```

In addition, it will work with:

```
int sign4 = Math.Sign(-5.2); // Double value, returns -1
int sign5 = Math.Sign(0.0m); // Decimal, returns 0
// ....
```

Comment: haha one of those functions I never needed to use, so never knew it existed. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would Math.Sign(0.01m) return?

Comment: @icemandind: 1 - Any positive number (no matter how small), with decimal, returns +1.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak21zcty.aspx

Answer (score 7):

```
int sign = Math.Sign(number);
```

It already exists.

Comment: I read in the documentation that Sign returns -1 or below for negative numbers. So i suspect, it is an implementational detail that it in fact returns -1, not a defined behavior. Thus it is not reliable and may change between releases.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int SignFunction(int number) 
{
    return number.CompareTo(0);
}
```

Comment: See my comment to Anthony Pegram's answer. It's an implementation detail that Int32's CompareTo function returns -1, 1 or 0 - not a specified behaviour. It could change between frameworks. Use Math.Sign.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int SignFunction( int input )
{
    if( input < 0 ) return -1;
    if( input > 0 ) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Falmarri LOL I guess one could argue this is portable to another implementation of C# that might not include the .NET Framework.

Comment: Indeed this function is a standard FPU operation, so I don't think someone could be made an implementation without it ;-) This also implies that this implementation is way slower than API.

Comment: This is exactly how the framework does it: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,551

Answer (score 3):

```
return input.CompareTo(0);
```

Comment: +1 since CompareTo is more or less implemented the same way as Math.Sign. Math.Sign has hardcoded the zero ;)

Comment: @Mikael: CompareTo suggests a very different usage, though.  Math.Sign is much better at telling the programmers following you about your original intent.

Comment: Strictly, IComparable.CompareTo only requires that the value it returns be negative, zero or positive to indicate the result of the comparison - it doesn't mandate that the result be -1, 0 or 1. Int16's implementation of CompareTo for shorts returns (int) x - (int) y for x.CompareTo(y).

In fact, to handle the result of CompareTo, you might want to pass it to Math.Sign to get a constrained value.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int SignFunction(int number) {
  return (number > 0) ? 
             1 : (number < 0) ? 
                    -1 : number;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think this is a perfect example of doing something the "clever" way with no benefit. That is: compare this to the answer provided by [Lucas Heneks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259509/a-function-to-return-a-sign/3259528#3259528). Not a programmer in the world wouldn't understand his version. Yours might cause some confusion (it shouldn't, but it might). They perform the same. See the argument?

Comment: @Dan I agree with you *in principle* about doing things too cleverly. But I beg to differ about ternary expressions. I don't think they are too hard to understand, IMHO :). But yes, I can see how this is not as easy to understand as a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

If `Math.Sign` did not exist, I would do this:

```
return x == 0 ? 0 : x / Math.Abs(x);
```

Comment: I suspect that Sign(int.MinValue) should return -1, rather than throwing an OverflowException, though. so maybe you shouldn't do that.

(to be clear: Math.Abs(int.MinValue) would be -int.MinValue, which is int.MaxValue+1... oops)

Comment: Thanks James, I didn't know that was how Abs is implemented.

AtliB what are you smoking?

Comment: Josh, compare your solution to e.g. BioBuckyBall solution... which is clearer and more efficient? The code doesn't reflect the intentions properly, has an unnecessary division and a method call.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Sign(int number)
{
    if(number==0)
       return 0;
    return number/Math.Abs(number);
}
```

Comment: Same problem as Josh above - int.MinValue fails.